# Rest Architcture - Request and Response Objects

Tags: rest

I have wrote a lot of rest services and the frontend at the last few weeks and I am still not sure if there is a better way than I have done it.

In some cases I have made mapping objects because at frontends an aggregation of object plus additional properties where needed. And also an advantage of mapping objects is that it is possible to set (special) default values.

My question now would be what you think about mapping objects because standard is do make REST services without mapping object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> standard is do make REST services without mapping object

Which standard? I never heard of such a standard, "REST" is an architectural style, so there are conventions, practices, but AFAIK no standard yet.

Anyway, you are mapping objects, which is a good practice. Doing so, you protect your domain model, which can evolve independently from the interface (Domain Driven Design / Anticorruption layer).

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was not sure about this because I aggregates different objects in backend like I need it in frontend. The REST concept I thought was that every resource has an id and if I need e.g. 10 resources in frontend than I have to request the backend ten times. I only request the backend one time and aggregate and map the objects in backend.

Comment: If you don't want to make many requests to your backend, set up a cache. You should avoid aggregating data just for display reasons: a REST resource should represent a concept, this concept can be an aggregate of many entities, but you shouldn't expect the API to compose the data for your view.

Comment: Just to clarify, REST *does* have a constraint that every resource must have an identifier. Resources however don't need to be 1-to-1 mapped to your domain model. Infact, that is somewhat of an anti-pattern.